# How send variables values between JBPM tasks?

Tags: java, database, jbpm, business-process-management, kie

I have a project that contains a Business process asset that retrieves data from the database as a list, I need to fetch all those data in Combobox to let the user choose, How can achieve this point? I tried to add a variable to the user that takes the list from the database task and presents it to the user as MultipleSelector, but not works, please help.

[image: result variable declared for ExcuteSQL task and choose variable declared for the user to pass the result and show it as MultipleSelector]
[image]

Comment: am I correct in believing this isn't as much about programming, as it is about learning how to use that tool?

Comment: it contains both, programming by java or using Business-central with little programming (what I use now)

Comment: so far, based on your question, all you try is setting some fields in a UI.

Comment: yes and I can point to java file to do some code as a data object, so if you have any code suggestion it can handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do all the necessary setup of the "Execute SQL" Service task as described [here](https://techblogtoprogram.wordpress.com/2020/06/02/how-to-configure-executesql-service-task-in-jbpm/).

Create a process model where you add the "Execute SQL" task followed by a Human task.
Next add a new Process variable of type the java.util.ArrayList to your process model.
Open the properties for the Execute SQL task, configure as assignments (data output) the previou created process variable.
Open the properties for the Human task, fill in actor and configure as assignments (data input) the list variable.

Create a new form where you choose the Human task of your process.
Pull the assigned variable from the left on the form. In the dialog choose as field type 'multipleselector', select 'required' and unselect 'read only'.

I found out that there exists a JBPM issue (https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBPM-9595) that blocks using the 'multipleselector' component. Until this is fixed you may want to use the 'multipleinput' instead.